# Substitution-permutation network

Tags: encryption, spn

Can anyone in 6th grade English explain the steps in the Substitution-permutation network algorithm or just point a link that does so? (which is included in many of the top modern algorithms)

[Wikiepedia's](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution-permutation_network) link is not really that helpful and I can not locate anything simple on the internet for beginners.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlzxpkdXP58 has a nice animation for AES as an example..

Comment: Thanks @HennoBrandsma I still did not move to AES. I want to master the SPN at first.

Comment: It's IMHO probably best understood by an example.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma do you know any link that provides a nice example ?

Comment: AES is an example, one could say the most important one.

Comment: I don't think that an example like AES is good. It's to complicated. In my opinion is the graphic on the right site of the wikipedia article a good example for a substitution permutation network. It's descripes exactly what a SPN is.

Comment: I agree Nova. I was able to get an idea of it by that graph.